# How to get a "loading" widget till jquery finish executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, widget

I am developing a `jQuery Mobile Web Page` where i import albums and photos from a facebook page and show them to the user.

It needs 4-5 seconds for my javascript to execute and import all the albums that i need.

My javascript looks like this :

```
    var albumPhotos = new Array();
    var albumThumbnails = new Array();
    var x=0;
    var next;
    // start the entire process
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK 
        FB.init({
            appId      : '564984346887426',                                                  // App ID from the app dashboard
            channelUrl : 'channel.html',                                                     // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status     : true,                                                               // Check Facebook Login status
            xfbml      : true                                                                // Look for social plugins on the page
        });

        FB.api('169070991963/albums', checkForErrorFirst(getAlbums));

    }
```

How do i get a jquery mobile widget that will start as soon as this function is executed and stop when the function finish?

Comment: use `$.mobile.loading('show / hide')` check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d39FX/

Comment: Thank you very much Omar that indeed helps. I can show the loading widget just before the API is called. But how do i check when the asynchronous call has finished so that i hide the widget? Here is the call to the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/   do you have any idea wheres the callback method here?

Comment: welcome! I couldn't find a callback there. you may need to search SO for similar issues.

Comment: Thank you again for taking a look Omar. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Start displaying widget in the method firing Ajax call and hide it in your callback method.

Comment: Thats what i read from the docs , but sadly there was not a coding example that i could understand. Could you give a simple example with code?

Comment: Create a div with zindex +1, hide it initially (by setting display to none). Now, before your FB.api call, change the display to blank (''), that will display the div. And in your checkForErrorFirst() method, change the display back to 'none'.